# find length of the ntext column type data in sql 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data in column which is of type NTEXT. I wanted to know the length of the data using query in sql 2000

-----Updates -----

HI,
    I had used the datalength thing earlier. But strangely its returning wrong values. Is there any other issue thts specific tht i shlould check.

Comment: In what way do they appear to be incorrect?

Comment: @alex k.  - length wise.

Comment: As in too long? If you view in QA/SMSS the values may appear truncated   .. DATALENGTH does what it ways on the tin

Comment: @ Alex K. - when i take out the data on to notepad and check it comes as 195 something and when i run datalength it gives as 250+.

Comment: If you select it in query-analyzer you need to change the "max characters to return" option in the results options, or use results to file which will not truncate iirc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want [`DATALENGTH()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258268%28v=sql.80%29.aspx);

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(ntextcol) FROM T
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DATALENGTH` itself.

For datatype `ntext`  *storage size in bytes, is two times the number of characters entered*

This might have caused you confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258268%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to get the length of a `NTEXT`

Answer (score 1):

```
Create table TestTable
(
    Id int identity,NtextCol NTEXT
)
GO
insert into TestTable
Select 'yogesh'
GO
insert into TestTable
Select 'bhadauriya'

Select Datalength(NtextCol)--get lenght of the data
From TestTable

Go
Drop table TestTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `LEN ( string_expression )`, where `string_expression` can be string expression to be evaluated. string_expression can be a constant, variable, or column of either character or binary data.

Comment: LEN() function does not work on Text, NText or Image data types

Comment: Ok! my bad. Thanks for rectifying me.

Comment: I thought it would be nice to let you know (btw I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 0):

ssilas777 mentioned "Storage size in bytes, is two times the number of characters entered"

With this in mind, `datalength([nTextColumn]) / 2 as nTextColumn_length` should return the specific answer being asked in the original post.